# Is there an OOB way in Ninject to configure service in singleton scope?

Tags: ninject, ninject-conventions

I am using `ninject` with `ninject.extenions.conventions`. I would like to use a convention to initialize some services as singletons. I know it is straightforward to add a `SingletonAttribute` and use it with `.WithAttribute<SingletonAttribute>()` during configuration. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: what does OOB stand for? Edit: i think you mean Out of the Box, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no singleton attribute being deliver with Ninject or ninject conventions.
The question is how you want to determine which types are bound `.InSingletonScope()`. Instead of an attribute you could also filter for types whose name end's with `Service`. Or which implement a specific interface. or which implement a specific attribute.

I would consider going for a name-based convention, if that does make sense. If not, you'll have to decide between shared interface or an attribute. If there's no shared methods/properties then a marker interface (empty interface) does not make sense and you should go with attributes.